# Whenever I try to open localhost it redirects me to Greenbone Security Assistant (https://localhost:9392/login/login.html) page

Tags: localhost

```
https://localhost:9392/login/login.html
```

I used `sudo apt-get autoremove openvas` but nothing change. Any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its [its own package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/greenbone-security-assistant) - so `apt remove greenbone-security-assistant` should help.

You might also want to run `apt autoremove` to clean out orphaned packages.

The redirection seems odd - so you may also want to check the settings on any web server you may be running